# NoMethodError undefined method `action_encoding_template' for Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I've stumbled upon strange error during #create action in one of my rails controllers:

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `action_encoding_template' for Controller
```

[image]

There is no clear way how to debug that.

Comment: version Rails 6.1.4.7

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to inherit from `ApplicationController`.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
...
end
```